# NullPointerException on render android layout

Tags: android-layout, android-studio

Any layout in my android project, generate a render exception:

**Android Studio 1.2 Beta**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.isThemeAppCompat(RenderSessionImpl.java:1203)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.findStatusBar(RenderSessionImpl.java:1066)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.init(RenderSessionImpl.java:209)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:319)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:350)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:497)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:485)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:894)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:485)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:590)
    at com.intellij.android.designer.designSurface.AndroidDesignerEditorPanel$6.run(AndroidDesignerEditorPanel.java:480)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:320)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:310)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$2.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:254)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:269)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:227)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:217)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
    at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:351)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Switching the preview rendering target from 22 to 21 made the error go away for me on Android Studio 1.2 Stable.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I got this error on the latest version of AS as of today, but for a different reason.

I renamed one of my app themes, then in all of the activity layout files that I had manually selected that theme for (in the theme drop down menu on the preview window), I was getting this error.

Once I realized this was the problem, I easily fixed it by just changing the theme to a valid/existing theme. Again I'm not talking about changing the defined theme for the activity, I'm talking about changing the PREVIEW theme.

Comment: This was my problem, and this is the solution

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug in Android Studio Beta 1.2.
After upgrading to 1.3, this does not occur

Comment: I wonder... As of today the newest release of Android Studio is 1.2 Beta3. This version still has this bug. How did you get hold of 1.3?

Comment: Still occurring in 1.3

Answer (score 0):

I second Siavash. I changed the name of one of my styles in styles.xml and started getting the same error message.

Look at the Design Preview toolbar, and check to ensure that the app theme name (AppTheme, AppBaseTheme, etc.) exists. Just click where it says AppTheme, and if the selection is not in the list of options, then it doesn't exist in your project. Try adding it to theme.xml or style.xml.